# unable to send json correctly in Typescript and Angular

Tags: json, typescript, angular6

I want to send a `JSON` from my Angular application. The structure of the `json` should be

`{"data":{"field1":"d","field2":"d","field3":["d"],"field4":["d"],"field5":["d"],"field6":"d","field7":"d"}}`

Some of the fields are string while other are arrays

Th `Angular` class to represent the `json` is

Data.class

```
  constructor (public field1:string,
               public field2:string,
               public field3:Array<string>,
               public field4:string, 
               public field5:Array<string>,
               public field6:Array<any>,
               public field7:string){}
```

Mydata.class

```
export class MyData{
   constructor(public data:Data){ }
```

However, the `json` being sent is `{"data":{"field1":"d","field2":"d","field3":"d","field4":"d","field5":"d","field6":"d","field7":"d"}}`

It looks like the `json` been sent contains only strings and not arrays. How could I send the `json` in the format `{"data":{"field1":"d","field2":"d","field3":["d"],"field4":["d"],"field5":["d"],"field6":"d","field7":"d"}}`

Comment: Typescript only checks types at compile time. Not at runtime. The actual object used at runtime contains strings instead of arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. So how could I send something like `{"data":{"field1":"d","field2":"d","field3":["d"],"field4":["d"],"field5":["d"],"field6":"d","field7":"d"}}`

Comment: By fixing the bug that stores strings in properties that are supposed to contain an array. We have no idea how you create and populate the data before sending it, but that's where the bug is located.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to accept your answer if you could convert your comment into one. I was creating `Data` by directly passing values of HTML fields. Now, I first created variables, eg, `let field4=[htmlform.field.value]`. Then I pass `field4` to `MyData`

Comment: You can simply delete it. Neither your question nor my answer is likely to ever be useful to anyone else. Happy to have helped.